# Simple JavaScript Interpolation Syntax

Tags: javascript, variables

I'm working on a brand new codebase and came across this line of JS that's completely boggling me. I've never seen this syntax before and can't figure out where it's from.

```
var userAddress = {!=userAddress!};
```

---

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            var userAddress = {!=userAddress!}; // <---- this syntax
        </script>
        <!--other head stuff-->
    </head>
    <body>
        lots of content
        <script scr="index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

What I also can't figure out is how this line is placed in the `<head>` section, yet the variable `userAddress` is defined in the `index.js` file which is loaded after this line is executed.

Any ideas are super appreciated.

Comment: That's likely part of some kind of templating engine. I doubt that's actually JavaScript.

Comment: Yep-- looks like a [DustJS comment](http://www.dustjs.com/docs/syntax/#comment).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @AlexanderNied but the comment syntax doesn't have the equals sign.

Comment: @AlexanderNied I don't think it's a comment. I would think that would go against the purpose of the variable declaration. Searching "html templating bang equals" makes me think it might be HAML.

Comment: Yes to both of you-- I should have been more careful-- just gave it a glance and didn't consider the context.  I agree w/ @Carcigenicate that it is probably some sort of templating engine, but yeah-- at second glance, its obviously not a comment.